# When we assign a variable to a single numpy.float64 via df.iloc method, will the df be exposed?

Tags: python, pandas

`df=pd.DataFrame([[2,4,6],[5,7,8],[2,4,6],[5,7,8],[2,4,6],[5,7,8]])`

```
   0  1  2
0  2  4  6
1  5  7  8
2  2  4  6
3  5  7  8
4  2  4  6
5  5  7  8
```

When we assign a variable to df.iloc, say `extract=df.iloc[2:5,0:2]`, I know that the data referenced to variable extract is exposed (mutable to df). However, if I want to just reference a variable to an exact number (say, `extract=df.iloc[3,4]`), is the original df still exposed to extract? (and what is the best way to get a copy of that single number to the variable exact?) When I do `print(type(df.iloc[3,4])`, I notice the type is `<class 'numpy.float64'>`. Is this an object reference or a primitive data ?

Comment: Error! Question not understood. If you do `extract=df.iloc[3,4]`, `extract` will store the value at `3, 4`, which does not exist in your example `df`. If you change `extract` the value in the `df` will not change. If you do `df.iloc[3,4] = 10`, then the value at `3, 4` will change to 10. And the type `<class 'numpy.float64'>` indicates the type of the single number at `3, 4`.

Comment: @Kartik, sorry my very bad and that was a genuine typo. say if extract=df.iloc[3,1], will extract store the 'value' at `3,4` as a 'primitive data' or it will store the 'reference' linked to df?

Comment: Primitive data.

Comment: Noted. So the fact that `print(type(extract))` shows numpy.int64 implies numpy.int64 is a kind of primitive data?

Comment: Well, it is primitive to the [`numpy` package](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html), not to Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  When you assign to `extract` what's returned by `df.iloc[3, 2]` and run `type(extract)`, you'll get `numpy.int64`.

You can tell that something will operate on the source dataframe by looking at the `is_copy` attribute.

```
extract = df.iloc[2:5, 0:2]

type(extract)

pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

---

```
print(extract.is_copy)

<weakref at 0x11b27cd60; to 'DataFrame' at 0x11bd64050>
```

So in this circumstance, `extract` is pointing to the same data that `df` is.

We can test this with various cases

```
extract = df.iloc[[4], 1]

type(extract)

pandas.core.series.Series
```

---

```
print(extract.is_copy)

None
```

---

```
extract = df.iloc[[2], [1]]

type(extract)

pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

---

```
print(extract.is_copy)

<weakref at 0x11b27c100; to 'DataFrame' at 0x11bd642d0>
```

---

It seems that if you slice `df` and maintain the dataframe dimensionality by using two indexers that produce arrays like `[2]`, `[0, 1]`, or `:2` then we will get a dataframe with connected data.

---

What about one indexer

```
extract = df.iloc[:2]

print(extract.is_copy)

<weakref at 0x11b27c100; to 'DataFrame' at 0x11bd642d0>
```

Yes, still a reference to data in `df`

If you want to ensure that you aren't

```
extract = df.iloc[[2], [1]].copy()

print(extract.is_copy)

None
```

Not a reference to data in `df`